# Algorithm to calculate maximum points by deleting a number

Tags: java, algorithm

I am going through this [leetcode algorithm](https://leetcode.com/articles/delete-and-earn/), I am trying to understand it by reading the explanation many times since 2 days, but I am not able to get the concept how the program is solved.

This is the problem statement:

> Given an array nums of integers, you can perform operations on the
>   array.
>
> In each operation, you pick any nums[i] and delete it to earn nums[i]
>   points. After, you must delete every element equal to nums[i] - 1 or
>   nums[i] + 1.
>
> You start with 0 points. Return the maximum number of points you can
>   earn by applying such operations.
>
> Example 1: Input: nums = [3, 4, 2] Output: 6 Explanation:  Delete 4 to
>   earn 4 points, consequently 3 is also deleted. Then, delete 2 to earn
>   2 points. 6 total points are earned.

Here is the explanation for on how it is solved:

Algorithm

> For each unique value k of nums in increasing order, let's maintain
>   the correct values of avoid and using, which represent the answer if
>   we don't take or take k respectively.
>
> If the new value k is adjacent to the previously largest value prev,
>   then the answer if we must take k is (the point value of k) + avoid,
>   while the answer if we must not take k is max(avoid, using).
>   Similarly, if k is not adjacent to prev, the answer if we must take k
>   is (the point value of k) + max(avoid, using), and the answer if we
>   must not take k is max(avoid, using).
>
> At the end, the best answer may or may not use the largest value in
>   nums, so we return max(avoid, using).

and the corresponding Java program:

```
public int deleteAndEarn(int[] nums) {
        int[] count = new int[10001];
        for (int x: nums) count[x]++;
        int avoid = 0, using = 0, prev = -1;

        for (int k = 0; k <= 10000; ++k) if (count[k] > 0) {
            int m = Math.max(avoid, using);
            if (k - 1 != prev) {
                using = k * count[k] + m;
                avoid = m;
            } else {
                using = k * count[k] + avoid;
                avoid = m;
            }
            prev = k;
        }
        return Math.max(avoid, using);
    }
```

I am not able to understand how `avoid` and `using` variables are used here and how it is solving the problem statement.

Can you please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Did you step through the code with a debugger to watch how the "objective function" works?

Comment: Do you not understand the explanation of how it is solved or how the code corresponds to that?

Comment: @Micromuncher, yes tried debugging using eclipse IDE

Comment: @juvian, I understood the code based on explanation. But I am nit able to understand the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the problem on that page.
The algorithm is based on a very nice trick. It is very easy to solve this problem when you process the input first before applying the algorithm.
The input is reorganized into buckets.

Lets say you have the input : `1 1 2 3 3 2 2 4 4 4`

You can reorganize it into

```
(Two 1s), (Three 2s), ( Two 3s), (Three 4s)
```

Now according to the problem, if you pick any bucket you should give up the bucket containing ( bucket-element-value - 1 ) and ( bucket-element-value + 1 ), which are actually adjacent ones to this bucket.

The problem now boils down to how would you pick buckets to get maximum sum given that constraint that you cannot get the adjacent bucket values ?

It is simple - As you go through the buckets, you have two things that you can do with a bucket. Either avoid it or use it.

If you avoid it, what is the maximum amount you can achieve - it depends on what you did with the previous one.

```
amountWhenAvoided[i] = Math.max( amountWhenAvoided[i-1], amountWhenTaken[i-1] );
```

If you use it, what is the maximum amount you can achieve? You get that bucket's value + whatever you got when you left/avoided the previous bucket.

```
amountWhenTaken[i] = amountWhenAvoided[i-1] + valueOfBucket[i]
```

Once you reach end of buckets the answer will be :

```
Math.max( amountWhenTaken[n], amountWhenAvoided[n] )
```

You could code this like:

```
public int deleteAndEarn( int[] nums ) {
  //reorganize.
  int[] valueOfBucket= new int[10001] //This is the maximum size of the buckets.

  for ( int num : nums ) {
     valueOfBucket[num] += num; //Populate each bucket.
  }

  //Now go through each bucket - remember - a bucket could be empty that's fine.
  int[] amountWhenTaken = new int[n];
  int[] amountWhenAvoided = new int[n];
  amountWhenTaken[0] = 0; //Because there are no buckets to start with - buckets start from 1
  amountWhenAvoided[0] = 0;
  for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
     amountWhenAvoided[i] = Math.max( amountWhenAvoided[i-1], amountWhenTaken[i-1] );
     amountWhenTaken[i] = amountWhenAvoided[i-1] + valueOfBucket[i];
  }
  return Math.max( amountWhenTaken[n], amountWhenAvoided[n] );
}
```

If you observe the code above, it is really not needed to do it with arrays. Because the current element in the array depends on its previous element, so we can do it with just two variables lets call them `avoiding, using`
Then the second for loop can be written as:

```
public int deleteAndEarn( int[] nums ) {
      //reorganize.
      int[] valueOfBucket= new int[10001] //This is the maximum size of the buckets.

      for ( int num : nums ) {
         valueOfBucket[num] += num; //Populate each bucket.
      }

      //Now go through each bucket - remember - a bucket could be empty that's fine.
      int using_prev = 0;
      int avoiding_prev = 0;
      int avoiding_curr = 0;
      int using_curr = 0;
      for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
         avoiding_curr = Math.max( avoiding_prev, using_prev);
         using_curr = avoiding_prev + valueOfBucket[i];
         avoiding_prev = avoiding_curr;
         using_prev = using_curr;
      }
      return Math.max( avoiding_curr, using_curr );
 }
```